# How can I connect a buzzer to the raspberry pi pico using C/Rust?

Tags: c, rust, pwm, raspberry-pi-pico

I have a raspberry pi pico and a buzzer which I connected to GPIO15. I can get it to buzz and play a few notes using MicroPython and Thony like this:

```py
from machine import Pin, PWM
from utime import sleep
buzzer = PWM(Pin(15))

tones = {
"C5": 523,
"CS5": 554,
"D5": 587,
"DS5": 622,
"E5": 659,
"F5": 698,
"FS5": 740,
"G5": 784,
"GS5": 831,
"A5": 880,
"AS5": 932,
"B5": 988,
}

song = ["E5","G5","A5","P","E5","G5","B5","A5","P","E5","G5","A5","P","G5","E5"]
led = Pin(25, Pin.OUT)


def playtone(frequency):
    buzzer.duty_u16(1000)
    buzzer.freq(frequency)
    led.toggle()

def bequiet():
    buzzer.duty_u16(0)

def playsong(mysong):
    for i in range(len(mysong)):
        if (mysong[i] == "P"):
            bequiet()
        else:
            playtone(tones[mysong[i]])
        sleep(0.3)
    bequiet()
playsong(song)
```

It works like a charm. However, I'm not a python person and I want to do the same thing using C/Rust. I've been doing research for days now and think I should use PWM to do it, but I'm very overwhelmed. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

[WiringPi](http://wiringpi.com/) is a fairly mature GPIO access library for RPi in C.

It also comes with things like [PWM](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi/blob/master/wiringPi/softPwm.h) and [tones](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi/blob/master/wiringPi/softTone.h) that should be very helpful.

Here is an example of how it can be used:

```c
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <softTone.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
#define BuzzPin 0
 
#define CL1 131
#define CL2 147
#define CL3 165
#define CL4 175
#define CL5 196
#define CL6 221
#define CL7 248
 
#define CM1 262
#define CM2 294
#define CM3 330
#define CM4 350
#define CM5 393
#define CM6 441
#define CM7 495
 
#define CH1 525
#define CH2 589
#define CH3 661
#define CH4 700
#define CH5 786
#define CH6 882
#define CH7 990
 
int song_1[] = {CM3,CM5,CM6,CM3,CM2,CM3,CM5,CM6,CH1,CM6,CM5,CM1,CM3,CM2,
CM2,CM3,CM5,CM2,CM3,CM3,CL6,CL6,CL6,CM1,CM2,CM3,CM2,CL7,
CL6,CM1,CL5};
 
int beat_1[] = {1,1,3,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,3};
 
 
int song_2[] = {CM1,CM1,CM1,CL5,CM3,CM3,CM3,CM1,CM1,CM3,CM5,CM5,CM4,CM3,CM2,
CM2,CM3,CM4,CM4,CM3,CM2,CM3,CM1,CM1,CM3,CM2,CL5,CL7,CM2,CM1
};
 
int beat_2[] = {1,1,1,3,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,3,3,2,3};
 
int main(void) {
  int i, j;

  if (wiringPiSetup() == -1) {
    When wiringpi initialization failed printf "WiringPi Failed"
    printf("14CORE | WiringPi initialization failed !");
    return 1;
  }

  if (softToneCreate(BuzzPin) == -1) {
    printf("14CORE| Soft Tone Failed !");
    return 1;
  }

  while (1) {
    printf("14CORE| Sound is generated...\n");

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(song_1) / 4; i++) {
      softToneWrite(BuzzPin, song_1[i]);
      delay(beat_1[i] * 500);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(song_2) / 4; i++) {
      softToneWrite(BuzzPin, song_2[i]);
      delay(beat_2[i] * 500);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```